# Query a nested data structure for locations

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-structures, recursive-query

I have this `locations` table:

| id | type | slug | parent_location_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Country | Germany | nil |
| 2 | FederalState | Hessen | 1 |
| 3 | City | Frankfurt | 2 |
| 4 | Street | Example | 3 |

I have a `tags` table which has a `belongs_to` logic to the `locations` table:

| id | name | location_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | blue | 1 |
| 2 | yellow | 2 |
| 3 | red | 2 |
| 4 | orange | 3 |
| 5 | white | 4 |
| 6 | black | 4 |

All tags of a location are displayed on webpages with this URL schema:

- http://localhost:4000/Germany
- http://localhost:4000/Germany/Hessen
- http://localhost:4000/Germany/Hessen/Frankfurt
- http://localhost:4000/Germany/Hessen/Frankfurt/Example
- http://localhost:4000/:country_slug/:federal_state_slug/:city_slug/:street_slug

To fetch all the `tags` for the last URL which would include all the `tags` for the Country, the FederalState, the City and the Street I run down the tree and query for the `:country_slug` first, then for the `:federal_state_slug`, then for the `:city_slug` and lastly for the `:street_slug`. Always in combination with the `parent_location_id` to make sure that it makes sense within the location tree. After that I combine all the location `ids` and run a select on `tags`. Needless to say that this takes for ever since I run 5 SQL queries in the worst case (for a street) and 2 in the best case (for a country).

I can't help but think that there must be a better data structure (I am happy to restructure the database) or some SQL magic so get this done with one SQL query. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive `cte`, in which you join your `tags` table onto each recursive query. The `cte` builds a `JSON` array of tag `id`s, which you can query later on:

```
with recursive cte(id, url, tag_path) as (
   select l.id, 'http://localhost:4000/'||l.slug, ('['||t.id||']')::jsonb 
   from locations l join tags t on t.location_id = l.id where l.parent_location_id is null
   union all
   select l.id, c.url||'/'||l.slug, c.tag_path||(t.id::text::jsonb) 
   from locations l join cte c on c.id = l.parent_location_id 
   join tags t on t.location_id = l.id
)
select * from cte;
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tkn3pune).